# How do I make a list of the ordered frequency of elements in a list of list

Tags: python, list

So I want to make a function that gives as return-value a `list` with the  ordered frequency of these names. Essentially all these sublist represent a pair of friends and I want to make a `list` of the most popular to the least popular person.
I've tried many things but these sublists are giving me problems.

```
a = [['Marie', 'Lucas'], ['Lucas', 'Patsy'], ['Emma', 'Lucas'], ['Emma', 'Kevin'], ['Peter', 'Emma'], ['Peter', 'Lucas'], ['Peter', 'Julie'], ['Suzy', 'Tobias']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first flatten the list with two imbricated loops, then use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the sorted list of most common names:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [['Marie', 'Lucas'], ['Lucas', 'Patsy'], ['Emma', 'Lucas'], ['Emma', 'Kevin'], ['Peter', 'Emma'], ['Peter', 'Lucas'], ['Peter', 'Julie'], ['Suzy', 'Tobias']]
flattened = [name for sublist in a for name in sublist]
counter = Counter(flattened)
out = [name for name, count in counter.most_common()]
print(out)
#['Lucas', 'Emma', 'Peter', 'Marie', 'Patsy', 'Kevin', 'Julie', 'Suzy', 'Tobias']
```

---

If you're not allowed to import anything, you can create the counter yourself, then sort its elements by count:

```
a = [['Marie', 'Lucas'], ['Lucas', 'Patsy'], ['Emma', 'Lucas'], ['Emma', 'Kevin'], ['Peter', 'Emma'], ['Peter', 'Lucas'], ['Peter', 'Julie'], ['Suzy', 'Tobias']]

# We flatten the list
flattened = [name for sublist in a for name in sublist]
# ['Marie', 'Lucas', 'Lucas', 'Patsy', 'Emma', 'Lucas', ...]

# We count the names in this list
counter = {}
for name in flattened:
    if name not in counter:
        counter[name] = 0
    counter[name] += 1

# dict.items() returns tuples (key, value), we sort by value 
out = [name for name, count in sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)]
print(out)
#['Lucas', 'Emma', 'Peter', 'Marie', 'Patsy', 'Kevin', 'Julie', 'Suzy', 'Tobias']
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't made clear that I cannot use import to fix this problem, do you need to change a lot is you can't use that?

Comment: Thank you so much. That's some beautiful coding, i love it.

Comment: You're welcome :) If you feel that an answer has answered your question, you may accept it (check mark on the left) and/or upvote it (once you have sufficient reputation (15))

Comment: I already had upvoted your answer, It said that it didn't display publicly because indeed I don't have 15 reputation but my vote is recorded and I didn't know about the check mark but now I checked it. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

So we have a list of lists. We can iterate through them like follows:

```py
for list in lists:
    for name in list:
        ....
```

Then we could continue with counting names and keeping track of the frequency in a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Using collections and itertools we can create a simple and readable solution.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

my_list = [['Marie', 'Lucas'], ['Lucas', 'Patsy'], ['Emma', 'Lucas'], ['Emma', 'Kevin'], ['Peter', 'Emma'], ['Peter', 'Lucas'], ['Peter', 'Julie'], ['Suzy', 'Tobias']]

#we first convert the list of lists to a single list
my_list_flattened = chain.from_iterable(a)

#count the number of occurances
my_list_count = Counter(my_list_flattened)

#finally for the order we can use most_common()
print(my_list_count.most_common())

#[('Lucas', 3), ('Emma', 2), ('Marie', 1), ('Patsy', 1), ('Kevin', 1)]
```